# COMPAQ Tower No Signal to monitor

Tags: power-supply, compaq-desktop-computer

I received a Compaq tower:

> Compaq Presario SR1224NX
>   Onboard VGA
>   Windows XP SP2

from a friend.

My plan was to turn this into an Ubuntu Server. It booted up with no problems even with the Ubuntu live disc. After a normal shutdown (*not* unplugging the power cord and *not* doing a hard shutdown with the power button), it would not restart even after SEVERAL attempts.

I realized the light next to the power supply would flash very rapidly. I researched and found out it was one of two things: a dead power supply or the cables to the motherboard and to the disks might be faulty, etc. Thus, I checked to ensure the cables were fine(and they were).

I purchased a Power Supply (this one has 400 watts, the initial had 250) and installed it. The tower was able to boot into the live disk and everything. After a normal shutdown, it now restarts but is not sending signal to my monitor. I have tried several monitors in which I know work perfectly but not with this tower (I recall that it did show display after replacing the power supply).

The monitors are ACER. This is different than most "no Signal" problems since I am not using an external Video Card, this is onboard VGA.

Answer (score 1):

OK to start with you have a Compaq Presario SR1224NX Desktop PC [(Product Specifications Here)](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00146969&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=441131&lang=en)
It sounds like it might be a motherboard problem.  You may not have a dedicated graphics card, but you do have a graphics card integrated into the motherboard chipset (Intel 845GV – No AGP) if the graphics subsystem has blown then your [motherboard](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00068983&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=441131&lang=en) is toast.  There is a fairly thorough troubleshooting guide from HP for “A monitor is connected to the computer and has power but does not display anything” [HERE](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph04760&tmp_task=solveCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=441131&lang=en).  This is a 2004 model system so HP will not have much in the way of support or parts available but you could order a [replacement motherboard](http://www.google.com/products?rls=ig&hl=en&q=DT049-69002) if need be.
The flashing power supply light can be caused by a motherboard issue as well FYI, but if it is working now then that probably was a PSU failure (You can review [THIS](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph06788&tmp_task=solveCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=441131) document for that one)

Comment: Also consider that older systems will have more power draws and no warranty, getting a new system would allow better efficiency (e.g. an atom box, in this case, could pay off its cost by reducing power usage in 1 year), and there is also warranty in case it breaks down. In my humble opinion, fixing old computer with possible motherboard problems is almost always not worth the cost (time costs, new hardware costs, etc) apart from nostalgic reasons...

Comment: @bubu – I actually agree with you on that. Repairing a computer with motherboard problems is often not worth it and a replacement may be a better value. In my defense I felt the intention of the question was in assisting with the actual diagnosis not in determining the value (or lack thereof) of repairing the system.